# How autowire will work in manual object instantiation?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

## `ServiceInvokerImpl.java`

```
Object lService = null;
lService = Class.forName("com.test.AssetServiceImpl").newInstance();
```

## `AssetServiceImpl.java`

```
public class AssetServiceImpl implements LogisticService {

    @Autowired
    private EntityLifeCycleManager entityLifeCycleManager;


    @Override
    @Transactional
    public FetchResults findAsset(String cls, QueryDetail query, OperationProperties props) {

        return entityLifeCycleManager.find("com.test.model.Asset", query, props);
}
```

## Question Description

When I instantiate `AssetServiceImpl` in `ServiceInvokerImpl.java`, it shows `Autowired` property `entityLifeCycleManager` of `AssetServiceImpl.java` as null. So, how autowire will work for manual instantiation for above scenario ?

Comment: It simply won't work, spring needs to be aware of this object for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

`@Autowired` only works for managed instances, i.e. object instances which are created by a Dependency Injection container (for `@Autowired`, this is Spring).

So if you just invoke `Class#getInstance()` (which is basically the same as instantiate with `new` operator), `@Autowired` is just ignored, and `entityLifeCycleManager` will be `null`.

If you still need to instantiate it manually (and not with Spring), you could use constructor injection and manually supply the dependency, for example:

```
public class AssetServiceImpl implements LogisticService {

    private final EntityLifeCycleManager entityLifeCycleManager;

    @Autowired
    public AssetServiceImpl(EntityLifeCycleManager entityLifeCycleManager) {
        this.entityLifeCycleManager = entityLifeCycleManager;
    }

    ...
```

and then instantiate it either with `new` operator:

```
EntityLifeCycleManager entityLifeCycleManager = //.. somehow obtain an EntityLifeCycleManager instance
LogisticService logisticService = new AssetServiceImpl(entityLifeCycleManager);
```

or via `Class`:

```
EntityLifeCycleManager entityLifeCycleManager = //.. somehow obtain an EntityLifeCycleManager instance
LogisticService logisticService = Class.forName("com.test.AssetServiceImpl").getConstructor(new Class[]{EntityLifeCycleManager.class}).newInstance(new Object[]{entityLifeCycleManager});
```

Please note that `@Autowired` annotation is moved to the constructor to still allow this service be created and autowired by Spring if you like so.

Also it is worth noting that field injection (which is used in our initial example) is not recommended. The reason is that same usecase: it is difficult to instantiate (and properly inject with collaborators) a class that uses field injection. Constructor injection is better in this regard.